# How much wisdom is the priesthood worth for the judges of the Sanhedrin?

Tags: halacha, rambam, beit-din-court

> It is a mitzvah to have priests and Levites included in the Great Sanhedrin... And if none can be found, it is permissible to have a court of exclusively Israelite judges. [Rambam's Hil. Sanhedrin 2.2](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Mishneh_Torah%2C_The_Sanhedrin_and_the_Penalties_within_their_Jurisdiction.2.2?&lang2=en)

If the judges are arranged on the seats according to their wisdom, how much wisdom is being a Kohen worth?

In other words, how much wisdom on a non-Kohen can be sacrificed in order to promote a Kohen into a Sanhedrin to fulfill this Mitzvah?

Comment: I think when the Rambam said "if none can be found" he meant "if none *worthy* can be found". And of course, ממזר ת"ח קודם לכה"ג עם הארץ.